# Finding the smallest positive integer $ n $ satisfying a modular identity.

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Is there any good way of finding the smallest positive integer $ n $ such that
$$
3^{n} \equiv 1 \pmod{1000000007}?
$$

Comment: What in the world are you talking about?

Comment: @Argument, Is it clear now ?

Comment: @Argument He wants to solve a modular logarithm problem.

Comment: Potato's edit has made everything crystal clear.

Comment: @AP: $n=500000003 m,   m \in \mathbb{Z}, m \ge 0$. Of course, $m=0$ is the smallest.

Comment: @Amzoti Do you have a proof that's the smallest?

Comment: @Amzoti, What is your approach ?

Comment: Amzoti may have done the following: By Fermat's little theorem, and because 1000000007 is prime, $3^{1000000007-1}\equiv 1 (\mod 1000000007)$. From this, you can conclude that the smallest positive $n$ divides 1000000006, which happens to be the product of two primes.

Comment: @Amzoti, question specifically asks for smallest *positive* integer $n$, etc., so "$m=0$" does not apply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First to make things clear, we are trying to find the multiplicative order of $3$ modulo $1000000007$

Now use the fact that $1000000007$ is a prime number and $(3,1000000007) = 1$. Then by Euler's Theorem and Fermat's Little Theorem we have:

$$3^{1000000007-1} \equiv 3^{1000000006}\equiv 1 \pmod {1000000007}$$

From Lagrange Theorem for group order we know that the order of one element in the group divides the order of the group. So let $G_{1000000007}$  denote the group of non-zero elements of the integers (mod ${1000000007}$) under multiplication, which has order $1000000007-1=1000000006$.

So we have: $ord_{1000000007}3 \mid 1000000006$

Because both numbers are natural numbers and $1000000006$, has $4$ divisors and those are:

$$ 1, \quad \quad 2, \quad \quad 500 000 003, \quad \quad 1000000006$$

That means that $ord_{1000000007}3$ must be one of them. It's easy to check that $ord_{1000000007}3=1$ and $ord_{1000000007}3=2$ isn't true. We now need to check whether $ord_{1000000007}3=500 000 003$.

From Euler's criterion we have:

$$\left(\frac{3}{1 000 000 007}\right) \equiv 3^{500 000 003} \pmod {1 000 000 007}$$

Where$\left(\frac{3}{1 000 000 007}\right)$ is Legendre symbol. From property of Legendre symbol we have:

$$\left(\frac{3}{1 000 000 007}\right) = (-1)^{\lfloor\frac{1 000 000 007+1}{6}\rfloor} = (-1)^{166666668} = 1$$

So this means that:

$$3^{500 000 003} \equiv 1 \pmod {1 000 000 007}$$

And $n=500 000 003$ is the smallest integer satisfying that congruence relation.

Comment: How to check that ord..3=1 and ord..3=2 aren't true?

Comment: If $ord_{1 000 000 007}3 = 1$. Then the following would hold:

$$3^{ord_{1 000 000 007}3} = 3^1 \equiv 1 \pmod {1 000 000 007}$$

which is obiously wrong. Use the same idea for $ord_{1 000 000 007}3 = 2$

Comment: Note that $\sqrt{3^{1000000006}} = \mid 3^{500 000 003} \mid$ and $\sqrt{1} = \mid1\mid$

So that means that $\mid3^{500 000 003}\mid \equiv \mid1\mid \pmod{1 000 000 007}$. 

Or $3^{500 000 003} \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{1 000 000 007}$

But as I said earlier, I can't think of a method better than using Wolfram Alpha to check whether it's conguent to $-1$ or to $1$

Comment: @Stefan4024: This smells of quadratic reciprocity. If $3$ is a square modulo $1000000007$, then $3^{500000003}$ must be $1$. On the other hand, half of the elements are squares, _and_ half of the elements are even powers of a generator, so "if" must be "if and only if" here.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes, how could I have forgotten? The Euler's criterion will do the work. I'll edit the answer.

Thanks for reminding me.